# phpmyadmin copy variables

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

How can i copy all variable list with values in phpmyadmin so I can import it in my local database.
As variables list I mean all settings variables list including sql-mode
[image]

Comment: You probably don't want to. That being said: `SHOW VARIABLES`.

Comment: You definitely don't want to use exactly the same settings on both servers as some settings are OS and/or hardware specific. Of course, of your hw and OS are exactly the same, you may get away with it, but would be extremely careful even under this specific circumstance!

Comment: @Shadow the problem is that I need to import an external database to my local pc, but im struggling with some tables. The main one is that I can't set default value for text fields. But on server its ok. I tried a lot of settings and ways to set it up, but still face it. I thought same setting could help me

Comment: This is the question you should have asked in the first place...